# How to make div onClick at the content only

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body
            {
                margin:0;   
            }
            .container
            {
                display:table;
                width:100vw;
                height:100vh;
                position:absolute;
                background:#000;
            }
            .helper
            {
                display:table-cell;
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
            .content
            {
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                width:500px;
                height:200px;
                background:#FFF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" onClick="alert('A')">
            <div class="helper">
                <div class="content" onClick="alert('C')">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to run some script when user click the content div and another script when user click the container div.

But when I click content div it run content script and container div.

How to make it only run content script when the content div is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a event.stopPropagation. Below is the code.

```
<div class="container" onclick="alert('A')">
            <div class="helper" id="content">
                <div class="content" onclick="alert('C') event.stopPropagation;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

[This is jsfiddle link with solved problem](http://jsfiddle.net/w96tk0x2/5/)

Comment: it only run alert('A'), I want to make it only run alert('C') when i click the content div

Comment: it's work.
it  only missing ";" after "alert('c')" and '()' after "event.stopPropagation"
thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you click on an element the event moves upwards or downwards. It depends on the 3rd parameter (true or false). Based on that you need to stop the propagation/bubbling to stop at the element you want it to stop.  Here is it . . .

> http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing